# Simplify EF connection string?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, connection-string

```
<add name="DemoModelContainer" connectionString="metadata=res://*/DataModel.Demo.csdl|res://*/DataModel.Demo.ssdl|res://*/DataModel.Demo.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DemoDev;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

This is just a connection string when I use EF4 in the project. It's ridiculous long. Is there any way to simplify this? To make it short and simple.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is no. This is connection string needed for EF provider when using EDMX file. You can buil connection string manually but it must have all these components.

Comment: In general - you're right, though there is one trick - i mentioned it

Answer (score 1):

You can use just:

```
<connectionString="metadata=res://*;provider=...
```

to omit specifying of csdl, ssdl, msl names.

Comment: Good trick but did you try it with more then one EDMX in the application.